# ng-model value not updating inside a kendo-ui widget definition

Tags: kendo-ui, angular-ngmodel, ng-show, kendo-datasource

I have a "loading" gif to show like this in angular: "ng-show='loading'". Which I call while my kendo-ui grid loads its dataSource from the server. For some reason, this guy $scope.loading=true wont update back to the UI. If I issue a $scope.$apply, then I get the error saying "$apply already in progress". Any idea on how to accomplish this? (I've read of k-ng-model, but not quite sure how to use it in this context)

-thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There not enough info for troubleshooting why `ng-show` is not triggering

I think for your case is better use kendo loading mask.([docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/ui#methods-progress))

Just set

`var element = $(grid); kendo.ui.progress(element, true);`

before calling getData

and `kendo.ui.progress(element, false);` when data received

Comment: Cool, it actually worked. Didnt know about this little nugget, thanks !!.